# How does swapcontext and getcontext work?

Tags: c, operating-system

I have this code below

```
volatile int done = 0;

int main() {


ucontext_t one;
ucontext_t two;


getcontext(&one);
printf("done = %d\n", done);
if(!done) {
done = 1;
printf(" - gurka -\n");
swapcontext(&two, &one);
printf(" - tomat -\n");
} else {
printf(" - salad -\n");
swapcontext(&one, &two);
printf(" - morot -\n");
}
printf(" - potät -\n");
return 0;
}
```

When it have executed i get this below

```
done = 0
- gurka -
done = 1
- salad -
- tomat -
- potät -
```

Why does it print out like this i have this function swapcontext() and in the man-pages it is written like this that it saves the context in another thread i don't understand why it writes out this?

Comment: Hello you should test this in C?

Comment: "POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of getcontext(), citing portability issues, and recommending that  applications  be  rewritten  to  use  POSIX threads instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **int swapcontext(ucontext_t *oucp, ucontext_t *ucp);**
>
> The `swapcontext()` function saves the current context in the structure
>   pointed to by oucp, and then activates the context pointed to by ucp.

The "Context" word, refers to the all of the important processor registers that represents current state of system. These registers list depends on the your machine architecture, But most important are: Stack Pointer, Program Counter, Link Register (For ARM, PowerPC, and PA-RISC that saves the return address) and etc. 
These registers will be stored into the `oucp`. Also, Will be loaded from the `ucp` for each activating context that due to set the PC value, It maybe does a jump.

So, According to the your code:

```
1 |volatile int done = 0;
2 |
3 |int main() {
4 |
5 |
6 | ucontext_t one;
7 | ucontext_t two;
8 |
9 |
10| getcontext(&one);
11| printf("done = %d\n", done);
12| if(!done) {
13|     done = 1;
14|     printf(" - gurka -\n");
15|     swapcontext(&two, &one);
16|     printf(" - tomat -\n");
17| } else {
18|     printf(" - salad -\n");
19|     swapcontext(&one, &two);
20|     printf(" - morot -\n");
21| }
22| printf(" - potät -\n");
23| return 0;
24|}
```

In the line #15, `one` context will be loaded. The code will jumps to the line #11.

In the line #19, `two` context will be loaded. The code will jumps to the line #16.

Note that `getcontext` just saves the current context.
You can achieve more details of these types of functions over the web by googling.